# How to get rid of the 'nlp.max_length' limit?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, maxlength

I am trying to do custom NER using spacy for articles; but when I start to train the model I get the error saying,
"[E088] Text of length 1021312 exceeds maximum of 1000000...."
Tried the following solutions :
i. Increasing nlp.max_length =  1500000
ii.Used spacy "en_core_web_lg" and then disabled the irrelevant spacy nlp pipelines.
iii. Tried nlp.max_length = len(txt) + 5000
iv. changing the max_lenghth in config file
v.nlp.max_length = len(text)
vi.splitting the data with '\n' and rejoined with space. (new line character “\n” is used to create a new line.)
doc = nlp.make_doc(" ".join(text.split('\n')))

But all in vain.

Comment: 1M characters is more like a book than an article. Changing `nlp.max_length` should work but can you not split your document up into multiple pieces that you feed to `nlp` separately?

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below. It worked for me.

```
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg',disable=['parser', 'tagger','ner'])

    nlp.max_length = 1198623
```